# Group Id and package name in Eclipse java web application using maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, web-applications, package

I plan to create a java web application project in Eclipse using 
`maven-archetype-webapp`. Suppose the project will have two packages:

1. `com.joe.config`
2. `com.joe.site`

What should I put in the `"Group Id"` and `"package"` when I create the project?

Should I input `com.joe` as the Group Id? If so, what should I put in the package section?

(When I type in the `"group id"` and `"artifact id"`, the package section automatically combine `GroupId` and `artifact`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**groupId** will identify your project uniquely across all projects, so you need to enforce a naming schema. 
eg:**com.joe** can be your **groupid**
Maven doesn't care what package names you use.
Further details can be found in the following link.
https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html